# Unable to push a npm artifact to Gitlab

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab

I'm trying to push a npm artifact and have it stored in Gitlab in its "Package Repositories" but am having trouble. Have tried a few different ways, with all giving the same error.

The below mostly comes from [How do I publish a private npm package with gitlab ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665511/how-do-i-publish-a-private-npm-package-with-gitlab-ci), and this is my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm config set //gitlab.com//api/v4/projects/700/packages/npm/:_authToken ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}
    - npm publish
```

But then gets an error of `need auth You need to authorize this machine using npm adduser`

I then run `npm adduser`, but that gets an error of `Username: npm ERR! cb() never called!`

And here is part of the package.json:

```
  "publishConfig": {
    "@foo:registry":"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/700/packages/npm"
  },
```

Another method I try is doing not doing the `npm config set...`, but instead doing `echo "//gitlab.com//api/v4/projects/700/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}">.npmrc`, but that gets the same errors.

And yet another method I try is not having `npm config` nor `echo //...`, but having this in the `.npmrc`:

```
@foo:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/700/packages/npm
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/700/packages/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}
```

But even that has the same errors.

Comment: the `cb() never called!` error is a known bug. try reinstalling npm.

Comment: In your example `.npmrc` file, you are missing `/npm/` before `:_authToken`. It should be `//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/700/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the troubleshooting steps that Gitlab provides.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/index.html#publish-an-npm-package-by-using-cicd

Comment: Which of these steps are for the `npm adduser` issue outlined in the question?

Comment: Please don't leave "RTFM" answers, even if you're legitimately pointing someone towards the docs. This type of answer is so minimally helpful that it's best just left as a comment.

Comment: @ParkerD You don't actually need `npm adduser` as the message says. If you're using an auth token, you can use that directly.

Comment: Agreed, the GitLab docs didn't provide troubleshooting steps for this. I submitted a ticket after I figured it out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77339968/1042151