# gitlab npm publish not working: This command requires you to be logged in

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, github-package-registry

I am new to this gitlab world.

I have one private project. I am able to publish the package using command prompt.

My .npmrc file

```
@ui-practice:registry=https://gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=PrivateToken
//gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/projects/MyProjectID/packages/npm/:_authToken=PrivateToken
```

But I am unable to publish using Gitlab CICD, it giving below error

```
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/projects/MyProjectID/packages/npm/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022
```

my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: node:latest


stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "@MyScope:registry=https://${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/packages/npm/">.npmrc
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}">>.npmrc
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}">>.npmrc
    - echo "Created the following .npmrc:"; cat .npmrc
    - npm publish
```

**CI_JOB_TOKEN** - I have created deploy token and added in gitlab variables

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "@MyScope/MyPackageName",
  "version": "1.0.23",
  "description": "My Library.",
  "publishConfig": {
    "@MyScope:registry": "https://gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/projects/MyProjectID/packages/npm/"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "web-test-runner \"./stories/**/*.test.js\" --node-resolve",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "chromatic": "npx chromatic --project-token=78290d9f7c4f",
    "build": "rimraf build && rollup -c",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm install && npm run build",
    "pack:dev": "npm pack && move *.tgz node_modules_offline/"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://gitlab.MyCompany.com/MyScope/MyPackageName.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@applitools/eyes-storybook": "^3.27.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.17.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.17.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.17.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-parameters": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-spread": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.2.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-strip": "^2.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.2",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/theming": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/web-components": "^6.4.19",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3": "^0.5.2",
    "chromatic": "^6.5.4",
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "html-minifier-terser": "^7.0.0-alpha.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.70.2",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^4.2.1",
    "rollup-plugin-minify-html-literals": "^1.2.6",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "^3.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "storybook-dark-mode": "^1.0.9",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@esm-bundle/chai": "^4.3.4-fix.0",
    "i18next": "^21.6.14",
    "lit-html": "^2.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "main": "build/cjs/index",
  "module": "build/esm/index",
  "files": [
    "build"
  ]
}
```

what is missing? any idea why gitlab asked me login again?

> need auth This command requires you to be logged in to

It's able to build the artifacts only issue in publishing the package using CICD, from visual studio terminal it's working fine.

Comment: I had the same problem, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77339968/1042151

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem and the reason it doesn't work for both of us is related to the registry endpoint we were using.
Both of us are using instance level endpoint, that can't be used to publish anything.

This is your .npmrc which contains, like mine,  a instance level registry

```
@MyScope:registry=https://gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=PrivateToken
//gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/projects/1233/packages/npm/:_authToken=PrivateToken
```

This is your extract from .gitlab-ci.yml

```
  script:
- echo "@MyScope:registry=https://${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/packages/npm/">.npmrc
- echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}">>.npmrc
- echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}">>.npmrc
- echo "Created the following .npmrc:"; cat .npmrc
- npm publish
```

My solution was change the first echo to:

```
  - echo "@MyScope:registry=https://${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/">.npmrc
```

This switched from instance level package to project level package where you can actually publish your package.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I could fix it with the right url in package.json. Hope this helps.

```
"publishConfig": {
    "@company:registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/project_id/packages/npm/"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the output of `echo "Created the following .npmrc:"; cat .npmrc` to your local `.npmrc` file. Are there any discrepancies? Is it possible that one or more of the environment variables within CI are blank?

Comment: Can you please suggest?

Comment: both the .npmrc files content are same

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your response, Both are same

**My local .npmrc file**

```
@MyScope:registry=https://gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=PrivateToken
//gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/projects/1233/packages/npm/:_authToken=PrivateToken
```

**And out put from .yml file i.e. cat .npmrc**

Created the following .npmrc:

```
@MyScope:registry=https://gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=PrivateToken
//gitlab.MyCompany.com/api/v4/projects/1233/packages/npm/:_authToken=PrivateToken
```